# Binding data with dropdown

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am making an application where there are two drop down's and one text box.There is JSON data i want to bind.I am able to bind the dropdown i.e on the change on first drop down the value of second drop down is changing.The problem is I am not able to bind data with the text field.Can any body help me?

The code for reference is HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: financialYear,value: animalTypea, optionsText: 'description',optionsValue: 'value'">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: animalsForType,value: animalType, optionsText: 'description',optionsValue: 'value'"></select>


<input type="text" data-bind="value: subject" />
```

and the JS code is

```
response.invocationResult.customerRequestMasterDetailBeans.forEach(function (item1) {
  if(item1.key == "") {
    self.financialYear.push(item1);
  }
});

self.financialYear = ko.observableArray([]);
self.animalTypea = ko.observable();

self.financialYeara = ko.observableArray([]);
self.animalTypea = ko.observable();

self.animalType = ko.observable();

self.subject = ko.observable();

self.animalsForType = ko.computed(function () {
  var selectedType = self.animalTypea();

  return !selectedType ? [] : response.invocationResult.customerRequestMasterDetailBeans.filter(function (data) {
    return data.key == selectedType;
  });
});

self.subject = ko.computed(function () {
  var selectedType = self.animalType();
  return !selectedType ? [] : response.invocationResult.customerRequestMasterDetailBeans.filter(function (data) {

    return data.subjectMessage == selectedType;
  });

});
```

and for reference the JSON is

```
{
    "customerRequestMasterDetailBeans": [
        {
            "requestMessage": "",
            "subjectMessage": "",
            "description": "DocumentRequest",
            "value": "DR",
            "formatMessage": "",
            "serviceCharge": "",
            "key": ""
        },
        {
            "requestMessage": "AservicechargeofRs50.00perstatementrequestwillbeapplied.Doyouwanttoproceed?",
            "subjectMessage": "HardcopyofStatementofAccount",
            "description": "StatementofAccount",
            "value": "SDR",
            "formatMessage": "PleasesendmeahardcopyofupdatedStatementofAccountatmyregisteredaddress.",
            "serviceCharge": "Rs50.00",
            "key": "DR"
        },
        {
            "requestMessage": "AservicechargeofRs50.00perstatementrequestwillbeapplied.Doyouwanttoproceed?",
            "subjectMessage": "HardcopyofForeclosureSimulation",
            "description": "ForeclosureSimulation",
            "value": "FCDR",
            "formatMessage": "PleasesendmeahardcopyofupdatedForeclosureSimulationatmyregisteredaddress.",
            "serviceCharge": "Rs50.00",
            "key": "DR"
        }
    ]
}
```

Actually I am trying to display Document request in first drop down and Statement of Account and Foreclosure Simulation in second drop down.Now if second drop down is populated with Statement of Account the text box should display Statement of Account and if Foreclosure Simulation then Hard copy of Foreclosure Simulation.

Comment: We could help you indeed. However we need a some things first. To start, we need the code you have tried posted in your question

Comment: Callum Linington,please check the details may this can help

Comment: You don't include any HTML for the text field. Does it have a `value` binding?

Comment: a fiddle or codepen reproducing the problem would be helpful, both to you  and us

Comment: First off, the properties are defined twice: `animalTypea` and `subject`. Second, the computed `subject` returns an array which you're trying to bind to a single textbox.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your problem is due to binding the *value* of an input to a *computed* value, which should depend on the values of the view-model and shouldn't be editable.

I would suggest you use the *text* binding instead of the *value* binding and using a span or div instead of an input as explained at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html.

```
<span data-bind="text: subject"></span>
```

If you really want to be able to edit the value of subject in an input node, (you might want to be able to change the selection by typing something different here) you could use a *writable* observable to tell knockout what you want to do when you type a value there (great explanation at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).